# Разный код для разных доменов

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтоб для разных доменов выполнялся разный код, а если такого домена нет, то выполнить другое. В js не силён, и поиск не дал результатов. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

```
 location.hostname
```

Ну и условие сделай, либо switch